# How to Copy Html From Awesomium web control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, awesomium

I am use Awesomium web control to view a web page inside my WPF application. I want to Copy HTML form it but I can`t find any way. I search Google about it but unfortunate I find only one result And that is not working for me.

I am follow this Link [interacting with awesominum webcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761334/interacting-with-awesominum-webcontrol) But it is not working.

I am try following code :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Clipboard.Clear();
    MyWebControl.SelectAll();
    MyWebControl.CopyHTML();
    var html = Clipboard.GetText();
    MessageBox.Show(html);
 }

<Custom:WebControl x:Name="MyWebControl"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="www.google.com" Margin="32,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425"/>
```

I Set Platform Target : 86x

I am using :

> awesomium_1_7_2_sdk_win
>
> Visual Studio 2012
>
> .NET 4.5

thank`s In advance.

Answer (score 0):

> awesomium_1_7_5_1_sdk_win
>
> Visual Studio 2015
>
> .NET 4.5

```
var html=MyWebControl.HTML.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string HTML_content = MyWebControl.HTML;
```

You may need to set the HTML in the listener bellow.

> private void webcontrolEventListener(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Hope this helps.