# Awesomium: Execute javascript, click on element

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

I'm trying to execute some piece of javascript in my awesomium `WebControl wb`.
An element `exampleDiv` shall be clicked when the user clicks on a button on my GUI.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (wb.IsDocumentReady)
    {
        wb.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('exampleDiv').click();");
    }
}
```

If I execute this piece of javascript in Chrome everything works fine.
If I execute this in awesomium nothing happens.
Simple things like `alert('Hello');` works fine but I didn't get anything else to work.

I also found this article [executing javascript in awesomium to click on a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088491/executing-javascript-in-awesomium-to-click-on-a-div) but it didn't help too.

I'm using the latest awesomium build (1.7.3).

Comment: Are you going to mark an answer correct?

Comment: @Dagrooms: Seems that I forgot to mark an answer as correct back in 2013. I don't know which one was correct if any.

Comment: I will vote one up for you to choose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if the issue is the version of chrome loaded with 1.7.3 or if its something else however i think what you should be doing is this:
`document.getElementById('exampleDiv').onclick()`

I tested something similar to your example with 1.7.3 using the attached debugger and i got the error:
`TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'click'`

That span has a wired click event on it, and i can trigger it using:
`document.getElementById('mySpan').click()` 
with chrome, but had to use `.onclick()` in awesomium.

Testing the same in the current version of chrome it works just fine. My guess is its most likely chrome 18, but I do not have the time at the moment to install it and verify.

If you are using jQuery then you could also use `$('#exampleDiv').click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

`dynamic submit = document.getElementById("exampleDiv");
 submit.Invoke("click");`

and this piece of code will be inside webcontrol -> loadingframeComplete section. Works 100% for me.